# how to float right while keeping elements in proper order?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I see a few questions on here that are like this one but their answers didnt work for me.

Here is a jsfiddle of whats happening [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJePw/1/)

I tried the things that were told to do in other questions

make the floating object display inline block, and make the container text-aline right. what else can be going wrong?

**html**

```
<nav>
    <h1>OWN WHAT YOU THINK</h1>
     <a href="#">JOIN</a>
     <a href="#">HISTORY</a>
     <a href="#">RESOURCES</a> 
     <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

**css**

```
nav{
height:61px;
width:400px;
color:white;
background-color: black;
margin:0 auto;
vertical-align: 10px;
line-height: 387%;
padding:0 50px 0 50px;
text-align: right;

}

nav h1{
    font-size:12px;
    float:left;
}

nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:100;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: you need to remove the `float` if you're going to use `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/yJePw/2/

Comment: Thank you, if i do this how does it know to stay to the right if im not floating right?

Comment: `inline-block` elements are affected by the `text-align` property of the parent, imagine they are words in a right aligned paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remvoe your float from Nav A

```
nav a{
    display:inline-block;

    color:white;
    margin-left:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:100;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xdJdv/